# Why Opera cant runs deeplinking | permission error

Tags: directory, permissions, deep-linking, opera, profile

I've deeplink for open my desktop application **it works on Chrome** but when i try with Opera, it reopens itself and says *"Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this machine."* What should I do now ?

btw **it works on Macbooks this error just for Windows.**

I tried launching Opera as admin but still getting error